# Memory crash with animation pre-loading cocos2d

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I have a problem with memory management in cocos2d project. For my app I need to build all my animations before the interaction beginning. I have three animation. 
Each one have like 20 png file with a resolution of 1300 x 1000 px and have a size of 200ko.

So in my initialization i just wrote :

```
self.animation = [CCAnimation animation];
[_animation setDelayPerUnit:0.04];
for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
{
   [_animation addSpriteFrameWithFilename:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image(%d)@2x.png",i]];
}
[[CCAnimationCache sharedAnimationCache] addAnimation:_animation name:@"animationWin"];
```

This kind of code is executed three times. If I run my app, it crashes directly. If i just pre-load 2 animations I have no crash.
If I set breakpoints inside my for loops I can see that it crashes inside it.

I don't know how to solve this problem ... do you have an idea ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each one have like 20 png file with a resolution of 1300 x 1000 px and
>   have a size of 200ko.

Let's do some math, shall we?

Under the assumption that the PNG files are 32-bit and you do not have NPOT (non-power-of-two) support enabled, each texture consumes:

1300x1000 => expanded to power of two => 2048x1024 => number of pixels => 2,097,152 => times 32-Bit (4 Bytes) color depth per pixel => 8 Megabytes => times 20 textures => tadaaa … a whopping 160 MB texture memory usage.

**Well there's your problem!**

The file size of the PNG doesn't matter. It's a compressed format. But textures are uncompressed, unless you switch to PVR which are really well compressed but you also get artifacts and discoloration.

Definitely best solution is to tune down the size and/or amount of artwork you're trying to load.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. I reduced the empty space on my PNGs and it's good now

Answer (score 2):

the following will purge stuff for you.

```
NSLog(@"AppDelegate<applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning> : before purging all caches");
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] dumpCachedTextureInfo];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeUnusedSpriteFrames];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData];
NSLog(@"AppDelegate<applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning> : after purging all caches");
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] dumpCachedTextureInfo];
```

Changing to PVR format will not help since it is the texture size that dictates the amount of memory (PVR will only benefit on 'disk' size and load time, not RAM required at run time). The depth of each pixel will:

```
+(void) mediumPixelFormat{
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444];
}
```

you can change the format at any point. Also i notice 1300x1000, that is very wasteful in POT. This will actually take as much room as a 2048x2048 texture. Any way you could work with your graphic artists to shave that to 1024x1024 , or combine the 3 textures into 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Well i think you are using too much memory. You should try to use spritesheets/batchnodes, another texture format like PVRTC and try with different pixel formats.

To help with all of the above i recommend [Texture Packer](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/)

Comment: f***. Is there a way to remove all previous sprites that I don't use anymore ?

Comment: CCSprites or textures (png)? If is the second you could try removeUnusedTextures in the texture cache

Comment: I tried to pop my old scene then reallocate my director and removing all cached textures then push my new scene ... The same

Comment: Use [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeUnusedSpriteFrames]; :)